# Java version different from JAVA_HOME CentOS7

Tags: java, linux, operating-system, environment-variables, centos7

I have a centOS7 server, and want to have JDK1.6_15 on it.
I update the /etc/profile scripts to have JAVA_HOME variable correct.
The PATH is also updated with JAVA_HOME in first place.

But, when I launch "java -version" command, I have JDK1.8 OpenJDK displayed !

When I launch the "alternatives --config java" command, I have only :

```
java-1.8.0-openjdk.x86_64 (/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.342.b07-1.el7_9.x86_64/jre/bin/java)
```

So I force things with :

```
alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /opt/jdk1.6.0_15/bin/java 1
alternatives --install /usr/bin/javac javac /opt/jdk1.6.0_15/bin/javac 1
```

It's ok now, but, it seems not really correct to me to do this, it's weird no ?

Is there a way to install properly with yum the OpenJDK1.6 but precisely 1.6.0_15 version, not another ?

Comment: I don't use CentOS but you can probably install the rpm with yum from [HERE](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-java-archive-javase6-downloads.html#license-lightbox)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, we couldn't do another way, it's the right way, so I let the things like they are